# Convertir array a objeto

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un array que quiero convertir a un array de objetos con propiedades... realmente ya llevo un rato quebrandome la cabeza con este problema que ya no sé como explicarme, pero tengo un array igual a este.
articulos = {101, 10, 102, 20, 103, 30} y quiero un que cada indice impar sea la propiedad "Articulo" y cada indice par sea la propiedad "Cantidad". Este array "articulos" lo estoy creando con una función each() de JQuery recorriendo todos los inputs de un div y haciendo push a un array vacío... les comparto mi código.

```
let articulos = [];
let arrArticulos = [];
let arrAux = {
    Articulo : 0,
    Cantidad : 0
};
conteo = 0;
let cantidad = false;
$('.ingresar-factura__articulos input').each(function(i){
    articulos.push($(this).val());
})
$.each(articulos, function(key, value){
    if (!cantidad) {
        arrAux['Articulo'] = value;
        cantidad = true;
    } else {
        arrAux['Cantidad'] = value;
        arrArticulos.push(arrAux);
        conteo++;
        cantidad = false;
    }
})
```

Esto funciona, el problema es que al final, el array sólo tiene los valores de los dos últimos inputs (son 4 en total, 2 para articulo y 2 para cantidad). Les comparto imagenes de la consola y de los inputs que tengo.

[image: Consola]

[image: Inputs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```
  let articulos = [];
  $('.ingresar-factura__articulos input').each(function(i, el) {
    articulos.push($(this).val());
  })
  let todos = []
  obj = {}
  $.each(articulos, function(key, value) {
    if (key % 2 == 0) {
      obj.Articulo = value;
    } else {
      obj.Cantidad = value;
      todos.push(obj)
      obj = {}
    }
  })
  console.log(todos)
```

### Explicación

Recorremos el array creado de artículos tal como el OP hacia, pero mirando si el índice es par o impar, y sabiendo que el índice de un array siempre empieza por 0, por lo tanto ese se corresponde con el artículo y si no es par entonces es la cantidad, de este modo:

```
if (key % 2 == 0) {
      obj.Articulo = value;
```

Mediante el [operador de resto %](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) verificamos si el resto es 0 o no (par o impar) y como decia, sabiendo que el primer índice es 0 el resto será también 0.

En este caso ese **value** lo agregamos a la propiedad **Articulo** de un objeto **obj** definido vacio previamente, y así ya tenemos la primera propiedad establecida del objeto.

En el siguiente ciclo el índice será impar y saltará al `} else {` donde hacemos lo siguiente:

```
    } else {
      obj.Cantidad = value;
      todos.push(obj)
      obj = {}
```

Es decir, primero asignamos el value a la propiedad **Cantidad** de ese objeto, acto seguido, como ya tenemos el objeto deseado completo,  lo incluimos en un array que he denominado **todos** y finalmente vaciamos el objecto **obj** para que vuelva a empezar de nuevo en el siguiente ciclo, y así hasta el final de los ciclos.

Una vez terminado el bucle **each()** mostramos el array de objetos creados con el `console.log(todos)`.

Comment: Hola @masterguru, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, literal tenía dos días sin saber cómo solucionar esto.

Comment: Me alegro que te haya funcionado, ahora lo explicaré un poco más para que quede constancia (primero siempre pregunto si sirve por si acaso)